# Get the sql query result without extra symbols or characters using batch?

Tags: batch, batch-file, mysql, sql

Like --disable-column-names option, do we have an option to get the sql query result in text file without  having the extra symbols or characters?

for example

```
mysql -u username -ppassword  --disable-column-names --execute "select rules from test">out.txt
```

i used above to get the result .but  in my test table contains below rules

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    rules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    select no from tabl1
    select name from tabl2 innerjoin select name from tabl3
    select id from tabl6
    select card from tabl3
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

here is script i used  which already mentioned above

```
mysql -u username -ppassword  --disable-column-names --execute "select rules from test">out.txt
```

when i used above query i get result like

```
    select no/n from tabl1
    select name/n from tabl2/n innerjoin/n select name/n from tabl3
    select id/n from tabl6
    select card/n from tabl3
```

is that any way to avoid this problem..i dont want special charcter like'/n ' in my text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Export MySQL Query Results to a File using Command Line

I performed this and I didn't get the `/n` characters so I'm not sure what's up with that. Perhaps the actual query results that are returned is the text content of the select statements and those `/n` characters are part of that content. I mention this because you say your results are the select statements with those characters.

Another solution you could use is [`SELECT INTO OUTFILE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/select-into-outfile/) with a syntax such as . . .

- `select no INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Folder/Path/out.txt' from tabl1`

  1. With this you could execute this logic at the `mysql` command line as such:

     > ```
     > mysql -u username -ppassword --execute "select no INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Folder/Path/out.txt' from tabl1"
     > ```
  2. Otherwise you could put the logic into a stored procedure and accept the full file path as the first parameter passed to it at run time and execute it from the `mysql` command line that way.

     > ```
     > mysql -u username -ppassword --execute "CALL StoredProcName('C:/Folder/Path/out.txt')"
     > ```

**Note:** For the full folder path that you specify which MySQL will utilize, be sure to use either a single forward slash (`/`) or else you double backslashes (`\\`) which separate folders and the file because the single backslash (`\`) is a MySQL escape character.

---

### Further Resources

- [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/select-into-outfile/#description)

  > **Description**
  >
  > `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` writes the resulting rows to a file, and
  >   allows the use of column and row terminators to specify a particular
  >   output format. The default is to terminate fields with tabs (`\t`) and
  >   lines with newlines (`\n`).
  >
  > The file must not exist. It cannot be overwritten. A user needs the
  >   [`FILE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#global-privileges) privilege to run this statement. Also, MariaDB needs permission
  >   to write files in the specified location. If the [`secure_file_priv`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#secure_file_priv)
  >   system variable is set to a non-empty directory name, the file can
  >   only be written to that directory.
  >
  > The `CHARACTER SET` clause specifies the [character set](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/data-types-character-sets-and-collations/) in which the
  >   results are to be written. Without the clause, no conversion takes
  >   place (the binary character set). In this case, if there are multiple
  >   character sets, the output will contain these too, and may not easily
  >   be able to be reloaded.
  >
  > [Source](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/select-into-outfile/#description)